# Converting Java Object to JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, struts2

I am using struts2 for Action and jquery for UI ...

I want to know how to convert a Map object to JSON object and send it back to UI ,

Now am able to print it in JSP page the normal java Map object :

```
{71=Heart XXX, 76=No Heart YYY}
```

But i want it to be like this :

```
{71:Heart XXX, 76:No Heart YYY}
```

How will i achieve this .... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(yourMap);
```

I wouldn't recommend putting this kind of code into a JSP, though. Things like these should live in a controller like a Servlet or Action class.

You also most definitely don't want the output to be:

```
{71:Heart XXX, 76:No Heart YYY}
```

but rather proper JSON like (quoted names, quoted string values):

```
{"71":"Heart XXX", "76":"No Heart YYY"}
```

Gson will output the latter.

Comment: thanks ... but i already used it and am getting it ... but according to my requirement i should not use this can you suggest any other way

Comment: If you're not allowed to use Gson, have a look at [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) or even [json.org/java](http://json.org/java/) (the latter is really simplistic and hard to use IMO). If you're not allowed to use any library, you're going to have a bad time getting the structure and escaping of JSON right. Don't do that, use a library.

Answer (score 6):

I personally use `struts2-json` plugin for this. It's very easy to use and you can easily  convert Map to Json and vice versa through some struts.xml entries.
Create a map and its getter/setters.

```
private Map<String, String> map= new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Define a global result as

```
 <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" default="false" />
```

in your `struts.xml` along with adding interceptor in your session stack.

```
<interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor" />

<action name="YouAction" class="YourActionClass" method="executeMethod">
         <result type="json"></result>
</action>
```

[More documentation can be found here](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html)

Answer (score 2):

To add to Ashish's answer, that is after adding the struts2-json-plugin.

I like to use the struts2-conventions-plugin where possible as such I have very little in my struts.xml and prefer to use mostly annotations instead.

To make your action return json when using conventions there are two steps: 1) have your action use the json-default package, 2) Define the action as having a json result type.

**JSON Annotations Example**

```
package org.test.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.ParentPackage;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
@ParentPackage("json-default")
@Result(type = "json")
public class JsonTest extends ActionSupport{
    private String name = "Hello World";
    private String language = "Java, I mean English";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }
}
```

Sometimes values more complex than primitives and you will want to prune the json returned, or sometimes you will want to put multiple actions into a single class (sometimes you get back a complicated structure and by pruning it certain ways you can make your work on the client easier). To do this we use include or exclude parameters.

**Example exclude language**

Modify the above result annotation to be:

```
@Result(type = "json", params = {
    "excludeProperties",
    "language"})
```

Another way to achieve the above is to explicitly state what properties we do want:

```
@Result(type = "json", params = {
    "includeProperties",
    "name"})
```

**Example Using wild cards with exclude parameter** 
Action code not supplied, good for trimming complicated objects

```
@Result(type = "json", params = {
    "excludeProperties",
    "punches.*.punchesCollection, *.punchesCollection.*"})
```

You can see with the plugin it is pretty hard to get easier than either the xml or annotation method.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of JSON libraries for Java on http://www.json.org/.
I would check out one of those.

Comment: While this is a valid answer, it should make an attemp to explain why one would forgo the built in struts 2 json support and drop down to a more labor intensive lower level solution.