# How do I control which properties of my data objects are serialized to the JSON response in Struts 2?

Tags: java, json, struts2

I've worked with struts for quite sometime now, but never figured the awesome "json" response type.

I have a large list of objects that I want to return to client. I use only a subset of these fields (typically 'displayName's) on the UI.

Is there a way to restrict the fields that are serialized as JSON back to the client?

One obvious approach I could think of is to create a view object which has subset of the fields. Please suggest the best practice here.

Comment: is that what you are looking at @[struts2 json with annotation approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12274582/1085285)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use exclude property of json plugin to exclude properties which you don't want to serialize.

```
<interceptor-ref name="json">
  <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
  <param name="excludeProperties">
    login.password,
    studentList.*\.sin
  </param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

For more details refer to [json-plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html)

Comment: Umesh, thanks for quick response. What I was looking for is some kind of annotation approach. However, the above solution also serves the purpose. I'll wait for more answers before marking it accepted. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Gopal There is no Struts 2 annotation-based approach when using the "json" result type. You could use GSON, serialize to a stream, and use Struts 2's "stream" response, although streaming a serialize action back feels weird to me--haven't given this much thought, but might.

Answer (score 1):

In my practice the easiest way I found for playing with JSON objects is GSON. Well documented and intuitive for using. Helped me in many cases.

It is very easy to solve your problem by using GSON.

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Excluding-Fields-From-Serialization-and-Deserialization

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Goals-for-Gson