# JSON Jquery to Struts2 action

Tags: java, jquery, json, struts2

I want to send my JSON object from Javscript to Struts2 Action.

Sample JSON Object

```
  {
        "lists":["list1","list2","list3","list4","list5"],
        "maps": {  
            "key4":"value4","key3":"value3","key5":"value5","key2":"value2","key1":"value1"
        },
        "number1":123456789,
        "numberarray1":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        "string1":"A",
        "stringarray1":["A1","B1"]
    }
```

My Jquery Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'json/JSON.action',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false ,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(){window.alert('Done');}
});
```

Struts.xml config

```
<action name="JSON" class="com.actions.json.JsonAction" method="getJSON">
    <result type="json"/>
</action>
```

My Action Class

```
public class JsonAction extends ActionSupport {


    private String data;


    public String getJSON() {


        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }



}
```

My Problem is how to receive the JSON Object in Action Class.

NOTE: POST OF JSON object is successful.. I just don't know how to receive it via Action Class.. PLEASE HELP
Thank you

Comment: can you share your Action class . Also have you also defined result type json in your struts.xml and  defined interceptor

Comment: `class="coma,ctions.json.JsonAction"` typo in `coma,ctions` ?

Comment: well you already using the plugin (json) so plugin in capable enough to fill your action class with the JSON data posted from the request, all you need to take care about the json format and some minor rules, have a look at the plugin docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There is a typo in your `struts.xml` entry
2. Have you defined tiles result and interceptor in `struts.xml` . **[Please see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12266588/1085285)**
3. The json you are sending to the server, doesn't contain any `data` key. So it will be always null. 
   Since json is denoted as objects. You need to convert JSON into Java objects in this way.

**Approach 1.**

Create setters for `lists,maps,number1,numberarray1,string1` and so on. In the top of **[this link](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html)**, is defined the way to do it. Then you can access all the variables in this way.

**Approach 2.**
In your javascript  define a new object.

```
 var sentData ={};
 sentData ["sentData "] = data;
// And in your ajax call , 
data: JSON.stringify(sentData),
```

And in your action class, create getters and setters for this.

```
Map<K.V> sentData = new HashMap<K,V>();
```

This will give you whole json object as a Map.

Comment: my problem is my data in action is always equal to null

Comment: @Ashish Gupta, Thank you for your explanations
I have tried this solution, and I can see that my data is read properly on a javascript side and being sent properly.  However, I cannot see the data in my Struts action.  I did it the same way as you say.  Is there any parameters or Interceptors to set in my struts.xml?  I have a feeling this maybe the case.

Thank you