# How to use jQuery to post JSON data to a Struts2 Action class

Tags: java, json, jquery, struts2

I've a problem sending data from jQuery to struts2 action class.
I have seen the question: [JSON Jquery to Struts2 action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746051/json-jquery-to-struts2-action) but I don't understand the solution quite well.

Here is my problem:

The json array is like this:

```
[{"id":"1","code":"111","name":"ddd"},
 {"id":"2","code":"222","name":"sss"},
 {"id":"3","code":"333","name":"eee"}]
```

I want to send the json data to the struts2 action class. 
The jQuery code is like this:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
$.ajax({
  url: "Update",
  type: "post",
  data:  data,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
  success : function(){
    alert("You made it!");
  }
});
```

However, in Chrome's Development Tool, I have seen the data submitted to the server side. But on the server side, I don't know how receive the json data.

Action:

```
public class Update extends ActionSupport{
    private String data;

    public String getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data){
        this.data= data;
    }

    public String execute(){
        System.out.println(data);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

In this way, `data` is null.

I've also tried to use a List to receive JSON data. Changing "data" type from String to `List<Node>`, it failed again. Probably because I don't quite understand the OGNL model which Struts2 is using.

Please Help Me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using the JSON plugin?

Comment: Yes, but I am not familiar with the plugin.

Answer (score 9):

```
{"id":"1","code":"111","name":"ddd"}
```

**Step 1 : Create a bean/pojo to accumulate/encapsulate the above fields**

```
class MyBean{
    String id,code,name;
    //getters & setters
}
```

**Step 2 : Change your action code to receive a List of MyBeans**

```
public class Update extends ActionSupport{
    private List<MyBean> data;

   //other code, getters & setters
}
```

**Step 3: Configure your action to de-serialize JSON data and fill the action fields (using json-plugin)**

```
    <action name="Update" class="Update">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
         <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
</action>
```

**Step 4 : Make necessary changes in the ajax request body being sent to match the action-params/fields**

```
var data = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
$.ajax({
  url: "Update",
  type: "post",
  data:  "data:"+data,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
  success : function(){
    alert("You made it!");
  }
});
```

The above code is untested.

Comment: Actually your suggestion is working! But I encounter another problem. I can send data to the JSON interceptor. But the interceptor throws exception saying my input is not well formed JSON(invalid char d). I think the JSON interceptor is reading my JSON object. As the first word of my JSON data is "data", I guess it is having problem process the

Comment: And then I add <param name="root">data</param> into the config file to   specify the root object. It still does not work well, reporting "Invalid root expression: 'data'." Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: please post the exact data that is being sent.

Answer (score 1):

Hey The problem is you are directly posting array of objects. So Struts2 don't know whicch method to call. Change your json data like below. Then it will work.

```
{"data":[{"id":"1","code":"111","name":"ddd"},
"id":"2","code":"222","name":"sss"},
{"id":"3","code":"333","name":"eee"}]}
```

Then inside the setter read with object

```
public void setData(List < Report > data) {
    System.out.println("Setter Call Flow");
    this.data = data;
}
```

Where Report is a java class contains id,code,name as it's members with setters and getters.

Answer (score 0):

To whom are struggling to this question, I just did several steps:

**Step 1. add dependency(maven)**

- make sure the version of this dependency matches the struts version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.22</version>
</dependency>
```

**Step 2. modify struts.xml**

- add `json-default` in your `<package>` label
- add `<interceptor-ref name="json" />` to my custom `<interceptor-stack>`, then it shoud be like the following:

```
<struts>
    <package name="your-custom-package-name" extends="struts-default json-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="your-custom-interceptor-stack">
                ...
                <interceptor-ref name="json" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="your-custom-interceptor-stack"/>
    </package>
```

**Step 3. Modify Action class**

- add `@ParentPackage("your-custom-package-name")` to your Action class
- create a javaBean to match the format of the transferring data
- remember the getter/setter of your javaBean
- **Make sure that your javaBean should implement `Serializable`**

```
@ParentPackage("your-custom-package-name")
public class XXXAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware 
{
    CustomJavaBean po;
    ...
    
    @Action(value="test")
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println(po != null);
    }

    public void setPo(CustomJavaBean po){
        this.po = po;
    }
    public CustomJavaBean getPo(){
        return this.po;
    }
}
```

**Step 4. follow the jQuery/ajax rule**

- Be sure to add extra layer on your raw data like `{"your-javaBean-name": data}` and transform it to the string by `JSON.stringify()`
- Here is my template if you need it:

```
let obj = {
    'addr': 'AAA',
    'postcode': 'AAA',
    'mail': 'AAA',
};
let data = {'po': obj};
data = JSON.stringify(data);
    
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "test.action",
    data: data,
    contentType:"application/json",
    success: function() {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

**Still**, if you meet the exception like `it's not well formed JSON (invalid char d)` then try to rename the javaBean in your Action class. For example, I encounter this problem that I put `CustomJavaBean data` in my Action class. It's solved after I changed to `CustomJavaBean po`.

By the way, who else uses struts these days, it sucks :P