# Refreshing (updating) individual rows of a table with the data returned by the action class using ajax call

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, jpa

from so many days i am trying to get this done,but m failing.
Have a look at my jsp once below:

Here i have one table and all each row i have refresh icon,i want to refresh individual row when clicked the icon.

onclick i am calling a function-> `refreshRecord(value);` value(parameter) is the fileid(unique)->i.e the first column of the table i am passing as a parameter to the function.

`ajax` is calling the `checkStatusAndNumRecs` aciton with the `fileId`,in action class i am calling my `JPA` method to get data from the database,its reading the row with that `fileId` what i have passed and putting it in `JSONObject`.

In jsp in ajax part its executing suuccess some time and error its executing most of the time,
when it is success,inside success part ,its failing to execute this line->var `obj = jQuery.parseJSON(eval(data));`

that means some times data is returning to ajax sometimes data is not coming back to ajax from action class.

THis is my jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>File Upload</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/button.css" />
        <link href="css/common-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
        <style>
        a{
        color:white;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
        </style>
         <script type="text/javascript">
        var id;
         function refreshRecord(value)
        {
            id = value;
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#refresh").click(function(){
               var fileId=id;
               $.ajax({
               type:"post",
                url:"checkStatusAndNumRecs",
               data:{fileId:fileId},
                success:function(data)
               {
                    alert(data);
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(eval(data));->THis statement is not executing
                    aler("after JSON OBJECT"+obj.status);
                   $("#div1").html(obj.status);
                   $("#div2").html(obj.records);
               },
               error:function(data)
            {
                $("#div1").html("It was a failure !!!");
            }
                });
                });
          });
        </script>    
        </head>
    <body>
    <%@include file="index1.html" %>
    <div class="box2">    
     <div class="box3"> 
    <s:property value="userId"/>
    </div>  
        <center><h2>FILE STATUS</h2></center>
    <center> 

        <form action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <label for="myFile" class="text">Upload your file:</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="upload"/>
            <input type="file" name="myFile" size="40"  class="file"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="button"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Refresh" class="button"/>
        </form>

        </center>
        <center>    
           <s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}">
        <form action="manage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="myFile" class="text">Click to manage service providers:</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Manage" class="button"/>
        </form>
        </s:if>
        </center>
          <center>
         <table border="1" class="displaytab" id="rtable">
         <s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}">
         <tr>   <td  colspan="10" style="background:#7395B8;color:white;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;"><center>Admin</center></td></tr>
         </s:if>
         <tr> 
         <th>FileId</th><th>File Name</th><th>Upload Date</th><th>#Records</th><th>Status</th><th>Estimated Time</th><th>Processed Records</th><th>Generate Report</th><th></th><s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}"><th>Controls</th></s:if>
         </tr>

         <s:iterator value="uploadList" var="m"> 
            <tr>   
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.fileId}" /></td> 
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.fileName}" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.uploadDate}" /></td>
            <td><div id="div2"><s:property value="%{#m.numRecords}" /></div></td>
            <td><div id="div1"><s:property value="%{#m.status}" /></div></td>
            <td>tbd</td>

            <td><s:property value="%{#m.numRecords}" /></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/generate.png" title="Generate Report"></a></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/refresh.png" title="Refresh" id="refresh" onclick="refreshRecord(<s:property value="%{#m.fileId}" />);"></a></td>
            <s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}">
                 <td><a href=""><img src="images/details.png"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/plus.png" title="Add Instance"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/minus.png" title="Remove Instance"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/download.png" title="Download"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/reconnect.png" title="Reconnect"></a></td>

            </s:if>
            </tr>
         </s:iterator>
         </table>
         </center>

         <br>
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>  
         <center>
         <s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}">

<!--          <select name="user names">
            <s:iterator value="userNamesList">
                <option value="emailColumn" > <s:property/>
                </option>
            </s:iterator>
        </select> -->

         <table border="1" class="displaytab" id="usertab">
         <s:if test="%{uploadListMap.size() != 0}">   
         <tr>   <td  colspan="10" style="background:#7395B8;color:white;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;">User Job Details</center></td></tr>
         <tr> 
         <th>FileId</th><th>File Name</th><th>Upload Date</th><th>#Records</th><th>Status</th><th>Estimated Time</th><th>Processed Records</th><th>Generate Report</th><th></th><s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}"><th>Controls</th></s:if>
         </tr>
         <s:iterator  value="%{uploadListMap}">
         <tr>   <td  colspan="10" style="background:#7395B8;color:white;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;"><center><s:property value="key"/></center></td>
         <s:iterator value="value" var="u">
         <tr>
            <td><s:property value="%{#u.fileId}" /></td> 
            <td><s:property value="%{#u.fileName}" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="%{#u.uploadDate}" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="%{#u.numRecords}" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="%{#u.status}" /></td>
            <td>tbd</td>
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.numRecords}" /></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/generate.png" title="Generate Report"></a></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/refresh.png" title="Refresh" id="refresh" onclick="refreshRecord(<s:property value="%{#u.fileId}" />);"></a></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/details.png"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/plus.png" title="Add Instance"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/minus.png" title="Remove Instance"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/download.png" title="Download"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/reconnect.png" title="Reconnect"></a></td>
         </tr>
         </s:iterator>
         </tr>
         </s:iterator>
         </s:if>
         </table>
         </s:if>
         </center> 
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my action class:

p

```
ackage com.mxui;

import com.mxui.db.api.PersistenceService;
import com.mxui.db.service.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class checkStatusAndNumRecsAction extends ActionSupport
{
    /**
     * 
     */

    private String status;

    public String getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) 
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    private long numRecords;

    public long getNumRecords()
    {
        return numRecords;
    }

    public void setNumRecords(long  numRecords) 
    {
        this.numRecords= numRecords;
    }

    private String fileId;
       public String getFileId()
    {
        return fileId;
    }

    public void setFileId(String fileId) 
    {
        this.fileId = fileId;
    }

    public String execute()
    {  
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        System.out.println("here inside action-------------");
        PersistenceService svc = PersistenceServiceImpl.getInstance();
        status = svc.getStatusByFileId(fileId);
        System.out.println("status is "+status);
        numRecords = svc.getNumRecordsByFileId(fileId);
        System.out.println("num records are "+numRecords);
        obj.put("status", status);
        obj.put("records", numRecords);
        System.out.print("json data is "+obj);
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

Please guide me in this ,i am struggling for this from so many days,and also i am new to ajax.
Thankyou in advance.

```
This is my struts.xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
   <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />
   <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" default="false" />

   <package name="struts" extends="struts-default">   
    <action name="RegisterationProcess" class="com.mxui.RegisterationFormAction">
     <result name="SUCCESS">registerationform.jsp</result>
     <result name="customerRegister">successregisteration.jsp</result>     
   </action>

     <action name="CheckUserValidation" class="com.mxui.CheckUserAction">
     <result name="SUCCESS">noofrows.jsp</result>
     </action>

   <action name="ProcessLogin" class="com.mxui.LoginAction">
       <result name="LOGIN" >login.jsp</result>
       <result name="REGISTER">registerationform.jsp</result>
       <result name="ERROR" type="redirect">login.jsp</result>
       <result name="FILEUPLOAD"  type="redirect">Upload</result>   
    </action>    

      <action name="Upload" class="com.mxui.UploadFileAction">        
      <result name="SUCCESS">fileupload.jsp</result>       
      <result name="LOGINERROR" type="redirect">ProcessLogin</result>
      <result name="PREVIEW" type="redirect">FilePreviewAction</result>       
      <result name="ERROR">error.jsp</result>
      </action>   

   <action name="FilePreviewAction" class="com.mxui.FilePreviewAction">
     <result name="SUCCESS">filepreview.jsp</result>
    <result name="JOBCREATED" type="redirect">Upload</result>
    <result name="ERROR" type="redirect">ProcessLogin</result>  
   </action> 

   <action name="ServiceProviderProcess" class="com.mxui.ServiceProviderAction">
     <result name="SUCCESS">CreateProvider.jsp</result>
     <result name="serviceprovider" type="redirect">Upload</result>     
   </action>

   <action name="UpdateServiceProviderProcess" class="com.mxui.UpdateServiceProviderAction">
     <result name="SUCCESS">updateserviceprovider.jsp</result>
     <result name="updated" type="redirect">Upload</result>     
   </action>

   <action name="manage" class="com.mxui.ManageServiceProviderAction">    
   <result name="SUCCESS">manageserviceprovider.jsp</result>   
      </action>
   </package>

   <package extends="struts-default,json-default" name="name" namespace="">
   <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor" />

   <action name="checkStatusAndNumRecs" class="com.mxui.checkStatusAndNumRecsAction" method="execute">
         <result type="json"></result>
   </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Comment: no its not workin i have included alertsome times i am able to see data in the alert some times its showing empty..

Comment: @pikrut yes i am using struts2.

Comment: I think you are working with struts. struts ajax support is different

Comment: ok i will post the ajax operation with struts2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746051/json-jquery-to-struts2-action?rq=1 Please check with this link

Comment: @pikrut i got the post ,but not getting what changes i should do in my code,can you give the todos for me.

Comment: alert(data);
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(eval(data));->THis statement is not executing
 *****aler("after JSON OBJECT"+obj.status);
 it should be 'alert("after JSON OBJECT"+obj.status);'

Comment: @pikrut means in single quotes it should be..

Comment: ok ok i got the last comment,it was spelling mistake,thanx.

Comment: other than this wat can i do to make it work

Comment: No it should be alert instead of aler. that is a bug i found in code i will post a detailed answer now please wait.

Comment: I have posted answer please check and find response is coming back or not.

Answer (score 0):

**In JSP Page**

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'checkStatusAndNumRecs',
        data:{fileId:fileId},
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(eval(data));->THis statement is not executing
            alert("after JSON OBJECT"+obj.status);
            $("#div1").html(obj.status);
            $("#div2").html(obj.records);
           },
           error:function(data)
        {
        $("#div1").html("It was a failure !!!");
        }
        });
        });
      });
```

**Struts.xml**

Define a global result as

```
 <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" default="false" />
```

For the action

```
<package extends="struts-default,json-default" name="name" namespace="">
   <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor" />

   <action name="YouAction" class="YourActionClass" method="executeMethod">
         <result type="json"></result>
   </action>
</package>
```

Comment: SEVERE: The content of element type "package" must match "(result-types?,interceptors?,default-interceptor-ref?,default-action-ref?,default-class-ref?,global-results?,global-exception-mappings?,action*)". at (null:62:14)
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "package" must match "(result-types?,interceptors?,default-interceptor-ref?,default-action-ref?,default-class-ref?,global-results?,global-exception-mappings?,action*)".          i am getting this error application is not running only.

Comment: i added that in struts.xml

Comment: Yes it should be success, answer edited please check.

Comment: dnt know why its giving 404 error requested resource not found

Comment: can i post my struts.xml file

Comment: i have posted my struts.xml file can you please check it.

Comment: I think you need to download JSON plugin. I can refer a link please go through this http://mycodefixes.blogspot.in/2011/01/using-struts-2-with-json-and-jquery.html